# Forward HTTPS client ip from Google Container Engine

Tags: nginx, http-headers, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running an nginx service in a docker container with Google Container Engine which forwards specific domain names to other services, like API, Frontend, etc. I have simple cluster for that with configured services. Nginx Service is Load Balance.

The REMOTE_ADDR environmental variable always contains an internal address in the Kubernetes cluster. I looked for is HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR but it's missing from the request headers. Is it possible to configure the service to save the external client ip in the requests?

Answer (score 3):

With the current implementation of L3 balancing (as of Kubernetes 1.4) it isn't possible to get the source IP address for a connection to your service.

It sounds like your use case might be well served by using an [Ingress](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) object (or by manually creating an [HTTP/S load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/)), which will put the source IP address into a the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header for easy retrieval by your backends.

Comment: I've created HTTPS load balancer and always get 502 error, because health checks didn't pass. Is it case that my cluster wrongly configured?

Comment: Did you add a firewall rule to allow them to hit your backends?

Comment: Yes, so the thing is that I have firewall rule to hit tag `my-https` and also health-check for IG, health check for group doesn't work and it restart VM and dropping tags which are used for firewall rule. I'm running containers on those VMs and there is nothing on VM actually that should reponse, but I have port mapping VM 443->443 (Container Nginx) and I think this is a problem.

Comment: Did you manually add a health check for the IG? What port range did you allow the health checks to come from and what are they checking for health?

Comment: Yes, I have manual setup for IG, they are going through 443 and should hit container with Nginx on 443. But as far as I understand it can't map to 443 inside container. But I have properly exposed ports in Docker

Comment: Do LBS can actually hit GCE(continer) with automatically created instances, where check path inside container, not VM ?

Comment: Some DevOps suggest to put nginx on actual VM instead separate container. So it's the only option for know?

Comment: How did you expose ports? Doing it in your dockerfile isn't sufficient when running the containers in Kubernetes. You also need to specify a host port in your pod definition (if you want to bind to a host port) or create a Kubernetes service backed by your pods and point the health check at that service.

Comment: yes, ofcourse I made those ports external in pod description. If I don't I couldn't even get to my webapp. I have Replication Controller + Service + Pod for my docker containers. Service is have external 443 and 80 ports.